# Split on dataset with some shared features?

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset with financial stock data, some of the features are shared, for example daily gold prices, while the stock price for each individual stock is different, the gold price would be the same for everybody that day.

When I split 80/10/10 randomly, it's "cheating" and while the result accuracy is great the actual real world live result is bad.

When I split sequentially, ie first 8 years of data in training, next year in validation, last year in testing.  The result accuracy is bad, and live testing is also bad.

What I want to ask is, should I do random split between just training and validation on first 9 years of data, then do testing on last year of data alone?

OR is sequentially as good as it's gonna get and I simply can't predict the future?

Comment: Validation set is very difficult to do when predicting time series. What is your prediction horizon? If it is J+1 then you should train on data until J and test on J+1. Careful though as adding the full historic might not be the best

Comment: It's J+1, but I am doing classification, not time series.  I thought doing it this way greatly simplify the problem.

Comment: I also converted the time series to a feature set ( ie J-1, J-2... ), I hope I didn't doom myself by using this approach...